# Parsing a key out of a key code

Tags: common-lisp, ccl

I am getting key events that contain asci key codes and I was wondering if there was any easy way to convert these to the actual key or character in common lisp.  I am using the ccl implementation which does not include int-char (which may or may not have worked for this task).

Comment: Can you give me a little more information about which library and functions you're using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [code-char](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_code_c.htm) function. It will return the character encoded by given integer. Bear in mind that CCL uses Unicode, not pure 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: Awesome thank you!  But it seems that my event gives me apple key-codes and code-char expects asci values.  For example my event gives me the key code 0 when a is pressed and for code-char to return #\a you would need to call (code-char 97).  Is there any conversion mechanism?